# How to deal with optional multipart data in Web API Post

Tags: asp.net-web-api, model-binding, multipartform-data

I need to create an ASP.NET Web API operation that takes in a few string fields plus an optional file.

Without the file requirement, I can use the standard:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(MyModel model)
```

With the file always being required, I can use:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post()
```

(this then uses a `MultipartStreamProvider` to extract the file and form data)

Given the fact that the file is optional though, I am not sure as to the best route to take. **My android client only uses *multipart/form-data* if a file is present**.

I can have two separate operations which seems inherently wrong. Alternatively, I can try and create a single operation that can handle both multipart/form-data and a normal post but this seems very awkward given the very different approaches required by web api in the two cases. As a third option, I can try to force all calls to use multipart at the android end but this may entail using another library which means more work.

I can't imagine I am the first person to experience this issue so am hoping someone will come up with a bright idea.